# Put a multi-line test message to MQ queue using MQ Explorer

Tags: ibm-mq

I would like to test some MQ-related functionality and I wanted to use MQ Explorer (v 7.5.0.2) to put a message to MQ queue. However, the input field accepts only one line messages

[image: MQ Explorer screenshot]

Is it possible to put multi-line messages using MQ Explorer? Using sequences like `\n` or `&#10;` does not work.

Comment: That functionality in MQ Explorer is meant to just send simple short test messages.  If you need to send multi line messages you would need to look for another tool.  I believe both Capitalware and MQGem provide tools for this purpose.  MQ itself at v8 and higher comes with the utility `dmpmqmsg` which can load and unload messages from a queue to a file, this may also be able to do what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc for suggestions. I'll try them. I think this is then valid answer ...

Comment: David, I'll try to write up a quick answer and give a little more detail with links to the two vendor sites as well as dmpmqmsg documentation from IBM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sad, but currently IBM MQ Explorer does not allow to send multiline message.

My workaround to this is to use JMSToolBox:
https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox

General description how to set it up with IBM MQ is here:
https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox/wiki/2.1-Setup-for-IBM-MQ

In my case two extra jars were needed:
com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.4.0.jar
json-20210307.jar